# Azure ADX: .alter-merge workload_group - failed

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

I searched the docs and used the example within:

[azure docs alter-merge-workload-group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/alter-merge-workload-group-command)

````
.alter-merge workload_group default ``` {
    "MaxExecutionTime": {
      "IsRelaxable": false,
      "Value": "00:01:00"
    }   
} } ```
````

This throws an error:

> Error
>
> Failed deserializing workload group from provided string

Why? The workload group is available within the ADX Cluster.

- searched azure docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend you compare the example in the document you've linked to with the actual command you ran - you can clearly see that you omitted the name of the property in which the request limits should be included (`RequestLimitsPolicy`).

*right (from the documentation):*

````
.alter-merge workload_group default ```
{
  "RequestLimitsPolicy": {
    "MaxExecutionTime": {
      "IsRelaxable": false,
      "Value": "00:01:00"
    }
  }
} ```
````

*wrong (from your question):*

````
.alter-merge workload_group default ``` {
    "MaxExecutionTime": {
      "IsRelaxable": false,
      "Value": "00:01:00"
    }   
} }```
````